# Select all nodes that have a specific name and a unique attribute in an XMLDocument

Tags: c#, unique, nodes, xmldocument

I have following XML file:

```
<RightsSetup>
  <Group Name="Sachbearbeiter">
    <List Url="Lists/List1">
      <RoleDefinition ID="3" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List2">
      <RoleDefinition ID="3" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List3">
      <RoleDefinition ID="3" />
    </List>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Administratoren">
    <List Url="Lists/List1">
      <RoleDefinition ID="3" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List2">
      <RoleDefinition ID="3" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List3">
      <RoleDefinition ID="3" />
    </List>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Finanzverwalter">
    <List Url="Lists/List1">
      <RoleDefinition ID="0" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List2">
      <RoleDefinition ID="0" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List3">
      <RoleDefinition ID="0" />
    </List>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Gutachter">
    <List Url="Lists/List1">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List2">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List3">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Mentoren">
    <List Url="Lists/List1">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List2">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List3">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Ausschuss">
    <List Url="Lists/List1">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List2">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
    <List Url="Lists/List3">
      <RoleDefinition ID="2" />
    </List>
  </Group>
</RightsSetup>
```

Now I need to select all `List` nodes that have a unique `URL` Attribute so I only end up with 3 nodes with my example.

I already select all `List` nodes using

```
this.XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//List");
```

But I don't know how to only select nodes that have a unique `Url` Attribute. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to group by URL using system.xml.linq

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq using a GROUPBY :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

             var groups = doc.Descendants("Group").Select(x => new {
                lists = x.Elements("List").Select(y => new {
                    url = (string)y.Attribute("Url"),
                    list = y
                })
                .Select(z => new { name = (string)x.Attribute("Name"), list = z.list, url = (string)z.url})
             }).SelectMany(y => y.lists).GroupBy(x => x.url).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```